# Defining variables inside if-statement

Tags: c, if-statement, variables, char

The code idea is to read the single characters from standard input. In case "y", or "n" was read, the program should print "YES!", or "NO!", respectively.

I tried to use `#define` directives within an `if` block:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define YES y 
#define NO n

int main()
{
    char letter = ' ';
    printf("for Yes enter : y\nfor No enter : n\n");
    letter = getchar();
    if (YES == letter)
    {
        printf("YES!");
    }
    else if (NO == letter)
    {
        printf("NO!");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("this option is not available");
    }
    printf("FUZZY");
    
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

This results in the following error:

```
Ex1.c: In function 'main':
Ex1.c:5:13: error: 'y' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define YES y
             ^
Ex1.c:13:5: note: in expansion of macro 'YES'
  if(YES == letter)
     ^~~
Ex1.c:5:13: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
 #define YES y
             ^
Ex1.c:13:5: note: in expansion of macro 'YES'
  if(YES == letter)
     ^~~
Ex1.c:6:12: error: 'n' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define NO n
            ^
Ex1.c:17:10: note: in expansion of macro 'NO'
  else if(NO == letter)
```

What's to do to and make this code work?

Comment: Replace the macros with *exactly* what you have them defined to be, then ask yourself if it makes any sense. I.e. `if (y == letter)` ??? Don't you mean, `if ('y' == letter)` ?

Comment: you are taking input a character and you have defined alias to a variable

Answer (score 3):

**Reason for "undeclared" error** : After pre-processing stage `if` statements will become as :

1. `if(YES == letter)` changes to `if(y == letter)`
2. `else if(NO == letter)` changes to `else if(n == letter)`

These two statements are the input to the compilation stage, after pre-processing. Clearly, `y` and `n` variables are not declared. Hence, the error.

**Solution :**

```
#define YES 'y' 
#define NO 'n'
```

After these changes `if` statements will be (after pre-processing stage):

1. `if(YES == letter)` changes to `if('y' == letter)`
2. `else if(NO == letter)` changes to `else if('n' == letter)`

Here, `'y'` and `'n'` are character constatns, not variables. So, you will not get "undeclared" error.

Answer (score 0):

First ,you should remove **#include <stdbool.h>**.

Second ,in your defines ,you declare y and x as a variables not as caracters ,to declare as a caracter you should make like this: 'x' , 'y'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define YES 'y'
#define NO 'n'

int main()
{
    char letter = ' ';
    printf("for Yes enter : y\nfor No enter : n\n");
    letter = getchar();
    if(YES == letter)
    {
        printf("YES!");
    }
    else if(NO == letter)
    {
        printf("NO!");
    }
    else
    {
       printf("this option is not available");
    }
    printf("\nFUZZY");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take y and n like character 'y' and 'n'